# Customize ActionBar tabs

Tags: android, tabs

The traditional way to implement ActionBar tabs has now been deprecated. So I have now implemented my tabs with this guide [github tabs](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout).

However I have a problem with styling the tabs with this guide. It seems you can only style the tabs through java code like this:

```
slidingTabLayout
        .setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return Color.RED;
            }
        });
```

This will only change the color of the indicator, but I want to change the background of the tabs in both selected, deselected and pressed states. The tradional way was to change the theme and make a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused" />

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />
</selector>
```

How can I do the same with the new way of doing tabs without having to install 3rd party librarys like this [github](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip)?

Comment: You need to go trough SlidingTabLayout class for customization.

Comment: Can you provide some more info about how to work with the TabColorizer?